# Good solidity smart contract tutorials, videos, examples

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, geth

I am looking for a good resource for solidity advanced smart contracts development free resource or books.

Scenarios like
- Crowdsale
- Insurance sector
- Banking

I have done some research on Open Zepplin which is a good resource for smart contracts but there is not a good explanation.

Any resource related help from the community will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've made 2 videos but the demand on such content is still not really high so I stopped recording new ones.

1. [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JExKs52oCsE)
2. [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtO-nCZyWIM)

And I also have a [repository](https://github.com/JincorTech/ico) which contains working contracts of token and kind of advanced crowdsale which is using Oracles, whitelist, bonuses, referall program, etc. It is pretty easy to start to play with because we've put everything into docker containers